# Bingbot in requesting stange, invalid URLs

Tags: bing, bing-webmaster-tools, bingbot

I have strange URLs that Bing is trying to crawl.  The Umbraco CMS throws exception when Bingbot request these URLs.  Bing appears to think that these are valid URLs, but the URLs do not exist.

The Bing Webmaster Tool screenshot :

[image]

How to remove this bug from Bing Webmaster Tool?

Comment: Keep in mind this may be a link of some sort on another site. As well, check the IP address. Many bots and hackers spoof user agents. How do you know it really is Bing? Only the IP address will tell you. Cheers!!

Comment: Is that screen shot of folders from Bing Webmaster tools?

Answer (score 1):

You can use htaccess to send a 410 - gone response, that should help with the Bing tools, and will stop your CMS from even seeing these requests.